# How to handle audio session interruption in macOS (Xcode)

Tags: swift, macos, avplayer

I build a radio-app for macOS. It starts playing when a phone call is received.

I've no clue why?

In the iOS and tvOS versions I handle this kind of interruptions with this code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AVAudioSessionInterruption(_:)), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
```

But `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification` is not available in macOS.

Does anyone know how to handle this?